# Removing all html comments except internet explorer comments using regex and php

Tags: php, regex, html

I am new in regex but need a code that would remove all html comments (`<!-- here -->`) but not internet explorer comments like (`<!--[if IE 7]> here <![endif]-->`). I have this code:
369

```
<?php
function stripTags($text, $tags)
{
  // replace the internet explorer comments tags so they do not get stripped  

  $text = preg_replace("<!--[if IE7] (.*?) <![endif]-->", "#?#", $text);

  // replace all the normal html comments
  $text =preg_replace('/<!--(.|\n)*?-->/g', '', $&text);


  // return internet explorer comments tags to their origial place

  $text = preg_replace("@#\?#@", "<!--[if IE7] (.*?) <![endif]-->", $text);

  return $text;
}
?>
```

Any help please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: When you convert the IE conditional comments, you don't store the original value anywhere.

Comment: Why do you need that? Comments do not have any influence on the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013499/stripping-html-comments-with-php-but-leaving-conditionals

Comment: I have seen the duplicate and its exactly what i needed. Thanks so much its great.

Answer (score 9):

Why not just use a negative lookahead to ensure that the comment does not start with `[if`? that is easier to read and the comment can contain also `[` and `]`.

```
<!--(?!\[if).*?-->
```

[See here online](http://www.rubular.com/r/aHoURowKFu)

Update: A lookahead assertion is a non capturing(zero length) expression (like an achor \b that checks for a word boundary), that means it does not consum the characters, it checks if the expression is matching and if yes it continues right after the character before the expression. The negative one is checking that there isn't the expression following. I better link to a manual, here is the [PerlReTut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind). Should be at that point no difference to php.

Comment: please can you explain how how negative look ahead works? Thanks

Comment: @Abhishek, I added some explanation and a link to my answer.

Comment: The rubular online is wonderfull it makes regular expressions less thorny. Thanks so much for the link

Comment: That is amazing - short and sweet - exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that no HTML comments on the page use the [ and ] characters, except for the if conditions, you can use:

`preg_replace("/<!--([^\[\]]*)-->/", "", $text);`

Answer (score 0):

try this
`\<!--[\(\.\|\\\w\)\*\?\d\-\+\}\{]+-->`

[image]