# Online parser to automatically strip ALL comments from HTML except for conditionals?

Tags: html, comments

Does anyone know of an online parser to automatically remove ALL comments EXCEPT for necessary conditionals? ie

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
```

I tried various forms of HTML5 minification but its buggy

Also saw these php solutions but would prefer to use an online parser if one already exists
[Removing all html comments except internet explorer comments using regex and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868968/removing-all-html-comments-except-internet-explorer-comments-using-regex-and-php)

[Stripping HTML Comments With PHP But Leaving Conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013499/stripping-html-comments-with-php-but-leaving-conditionals)

Answer (score 25):

Here, just made one for you: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/BUVkS/show/

If you want to see the source, it is here: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/BUVkS/

Put your HTML code inside, then click <kbd>remove comments</kbd>.
It will then remove all comments and left with the conditionals.

(Used that PHP regular expression you put ([the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1013864/283863)) and I put it into JavaScript **plus** a little modification to match newlines)

```
/<!--(?!\s*(?:\[if [^\]]+]|<!|>))(?:(?!-->)(.|\n))*-->/g
```

Comment: @user01 - Go to my demo, type in some HTML code with comments in it, click on remove comment.

Comment: Actually your code fails when there are new line characters in the comments. Try out after pressing `Enter` in between one of your comments. Otherwise its ok.

Comment: Excellent! I'll add to bookmarks this awesome tool!

Comment: This script removes JavaScript code inside <script> tags, if it was wrapped with HTML comments, like this: http://javascript.about.com/library/blhtmcmt.htm

Answer (score 3):

I've found this online js comment removal tool that seems to work fine

http://james.padolsey.com/demos/comment-removal-js.html

Comment: The poster's looking for something to strip comments from HTML.